# .net 5.0 signature change of System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize()

Tags: .net-5, system.text.json

I am attempting the step from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0 and get a bunch of nullability warnings at the uses of `Deserialize<TValue>(String, JsonSerializerOptions)`. A quick investigation shows that the signature has changed from

`public static TValue Deserialize<TValue> (string json, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options = default);` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1_System_String_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_)) in .NET Core 3.1 to

`public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue> (string json, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions? options = default);` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1_System_String_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_)) in .NET 5.0.

It looks as a reasonable change, but I haven't been able to provoke a null to actually be returned, since all bad input/bad use will throw an exception in my experiments, and the documentation does not describe why the call would return a null as far as I can tell.

It seems a bit unnecessary to add null return checks to all our uses, if failed deserialization will throw rather than returning null.

What am I missing?

Comment: *I haven't been able to provoke a null to actually be returned* - not sure what you tried, but `null` is a perfectly valid JSON value according to the [standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so if you just do `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>("null")` then `null` is returned, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/WTHbdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [original JSON proposal](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), the text `null` is perfectly well-formed JSON:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or **null**, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

This is further clarified in [RFC 8259: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2) which states that a well-formed JSON text need be nothing more than a single primitive value including `null`:

> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens.  The set of tokens includes six structural characters, strings, numbers, and three literal names [false, true and null].
>
> A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.  Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.

Since `null` is a well-formed JSON text according to this most recent JSON RFC, [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer) will not throw when deserializing it to a reference type or nullable value type, and will instead just return a null value:

```
object? obj1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>("null"); // Does not throw; explicitly typed for clarity.
Assert.IsNull(obj1);     // Passes
var array = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int []>("null");    // Does not throw;
Assert.IsNull(array);    // Passes
var nullable = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int?>("null");   // Does not throw;
Assert.IsNull(nullable); // Passes
```

Conversely the following generates a compiler warning:

```
#nullable enable
object obj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>("null"); // Compiler warning: Converting null literal or possible value to non-nullable type;
```

And the following throws, since an `int` is a non-nullable value type to which `null` **cannot** be assigned:

```
var i = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>("null");  // Throws, since int is a non-nullable value type.
```

If you want to an exception to be thrown when deserializing the JSON text `null`, you could add the following extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowOnNull<T>(this T? value) where T : class => value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

And do:

```
var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(json).ThrowOnNull();
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WTHbdo).